# Cannot delete a virtual machine

Tags: linux, azure, centos7, virtual-machines, service

I created a VM in France Central but the creation has failed because of:

**"Error: Code="AllocationFailed" Message="Allocation failed. We do not have sufficient capacity for the requested VM size in this region. Read more about improving likelihood of allocation suc
cess at http://aka.ms/allocation-guidance"**

I tried to delete the VM and now the VM is present in the list but when I click on it I can read the following message:

"Introuvable"

I tried to delete the vm with Azure cli but it didn't work.

Please, how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to simply wait.

Azure can be *really* slow at times when performing asynchronous tasks (even more so when a deployment fails and needs to be cleaned up). It's somewhat common for deleted resources to keep showing up for a while.